# Google Analytics Query

Tags: google-analytics

[image: code]

I used `query.getUrl()` for bring low-directory values.

But, I just wanted to bring each Url value. Like... wanna get the value form the lower "/mypage".

How can I get the value? Should I change the query in `query.getUrl()`?

Comment: As a new user of Stackoverflow you are not allowed to link to images. Maybe using some code snippets will help users answer your question.

Comment: @kiwiupower New users *can* link to images - they just don't have the privilege to embed them into a post.

Comment: Hi user6741629 - instead of showing your code in a screenshot, you should paste a snippet of your code into the question. That will make it more readable for everybody.